# BlueZ 5でラズベリーパイをBluetoothスピーカーとペアリングする方法

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluez

ラズベリーパイからBluetoothスピーカーを使いたいのですがペアリングが上手くいかず再生をできずに困っています。

ラズベリーパイにログインして`hcitool`で

```
$ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
    00:25:DB:96:09:5E   MEOSOUND003
```

と一覧には出てくるのですが

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]#
```

として表示はされても入力を`Ctrl+c`の強制終了しか受け付けてくれません。

`BlueZ 4`でおなじ質問を英語版スタックフローでしてペアリングまでは教えて頂いてできたのですが、その後BLEを使用すると`BlueZ 4`では動かなかったために`BlueZ 5`に上げたところ同様の問題に嵌ってしまいました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273935/cant-pairing-with-bluetooth-speaker-by-using-bluez-simple-agent

それとペアリングは自動で行われるようにしたいのでBluetoothの内部シェル(?)を使わない方法を探しています。

何か良い方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

sudo bluetoothctl -a
で試してはいかがでしょうか。